# How can I view the pull request URL for the current branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

After pushing a change, I see text like this:

```
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 478 bytes | 239.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
remote: Create pull request for my-branch => master-branch
remote:   https://bitbucket.org/my-company/repo/pull-requests/12345
```

But if I don't make a PR at that time, and the text scrolls out of view, that URL is gone.  How can I simply generate or re-view that URL without making a change and committing/pushing again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to generate the URL using a batch file like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal 
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ( 
    'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD'
) do ( 
    set branch=%%a
    set url=https://bitbucket.org/my-company/repo/pull-requests/new?source=%%a^^^&t=1
) 

echo %url%
endlocal
```

It simply grabs the current git branch and puts in a string, then echoes the string.

Comment: You can sophisticate this a little: `alias pr_url="https://bitbucket.org/$(git remote -v | head -n 1 | grep -oP '[\w+_]+\/[\w+_]+')/pull-requests/new?source=$(git branch --show-current)"`

Comment: @ScottAnderson: great! Event better: ```alias pr_url="https://bitbucket.org/$COMPANY_NAME/$(basename `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`)$(git remote -v | head -n 1 | grep -oP '[\w+_]+\/[\w+_]+')/pull-requests/new?source=$(git branch --show-current)"```

Answer (score 6):

This pull request URL is not a git feature but a message generated by a  hook script on the BitBucket server.

On a  BitBucket server, you can disable it globally with: [How do I disable the remote create pull request message when pushing changes?](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/how-do-i-disable-the-remote-create-pull-request-message-when-pushing-changes-701268506.html). On the BitBucket cloud you cannot disable it.

One soultion to obtain this message would be to simulate a `git pull` with the [`--dry-run`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---dry-run) option, such as :

```
git pull --dry-run
```

but if this is not enough to trigger the hook, probably that the only way is to go through the BitBucket web interface.

Comment: That isn't Bitbucket Server - that's Bitbucket Cloud.

Answer (score 2):

The URL you've listed here is for a pull request that already exists - the "View pull request" text is the giveaway there. Existing pull requests have an ID in the URL, which you'll need to specify; if you don't know the ID, then you'll need to get the URL from the GUI (`https://bitbucket.org/owner/repo/pull-requests/` is probably the easiest place to find it).

If there isn't already a pull request for your branch, then the "Create pull requests" link that the hook generates is `https://bitbucket.org/owner/repo/pull-requests/new?source=branchname&t=1`.

Answer (score 2):

Bash version:

```
#!/bin/bash

org="myOrg"
branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
repo_dir=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
repo=$(basename ${repo_dir})
url="https://bitbucket.org/${org}/${repo}/pull-requests/new?source=${branch}&t=1"

echo $url
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a pull request using a web browser (bitbucket web interface), go to the `branch` web page of your branch, or the `branches` page of your bitbucket repo.

Using the example in the question:

> ```
> remote: Create pull request for my-branch => master-branch
> remote:   https://bitbucket.org/my-company/repo/pull-requests/12345
> ```

We can go to
`https://bitbucket.org/my-company/repo/branch/my-branch`, there is a "Create pull request" link.

Or we can go to
`https://bitbucket.org/my-company/repo/branches`,
there is a column named "Pull request", and for branches that don't have an existing pull request, there is a "create" link.